# Crear con Hooks función para habilitar y desesabilitar button disable

Tags: reactjs

Estimados su apoyo por favor, nesecito crear una función con Hooks, donde cuando los 2 checkbox estén marcados o checked y se desabilite o remueva el disable del button. lo estuve intentando y no lo he logrado dejo un ejemplo de como tengo el código y que podría probar, Gracias por el aporte.

```js
import React from "react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const CheckButton = () => {
  const [habilta, setHabilita] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox" />
        <input id="check2" name="check2" type="checkbox" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <button disabled>Continuar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckButton;
```

Comment: Y donde llamas el estado de habilitado y la función setter de ese estado?

Comment: no lo he creado, por que intente una pero no logro obtener el resultado que busco, por eso estoy pidiendo un apoyo, Gracias

Comment: Perdona pero es que además de numerosos errores ortográficos, de formato y de redacción en tus últimas preguntas y que siempre pides que te "den un ejemplo" no pareces esforzarte sino esperar que te de todas las soluciones la comunidad, ni siquiera comentas en las respuestas que te han dado o terminas de escribir bien tu código con ejemplos reproducibles. Acá lo que falta es más repasar React que esperar que te den el código hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado para quien le sirva, no escatimo de compartir conocimientos y no me atribuyo dones de un gran erudito en el tema solo comparto conocimiento me gusta enseñar es una comunidad de ayuda... que tengan bue día...

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const CheckButton = () => {
  const [onehabilita, setOnehabilita] = useState(true);
  const [twohabilita, setTwohabilita] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input id="check1" name="check1" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setOnehabilita(!onehabilita)} />
        <input id="check2" name="check2" type="checkbox" onChange={() => setTwohabilita(!twohabilita)} />
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" className="continue emite" disabled={onehabilita || twohabilita }>Continuar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckButton;
```